# Software for testing responsive emails

Tags: email, windows-phone

Does anybody know if there is software for testing responsive emails on Windows Phone's different OS versions (7.1 - 8.0)?. I'm already working with Email On Acid, but they don't provide this option yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could always install the windows phone developer tools and set up an email account in the emulator. You propably only have to test wp8 with different resolutions which can also be done there.

Comment: That's what I figured I'd do but the problem I have with the developer tools is that if you want to test with wp8 you have to actually run Windows 8 which I don't... So your answer is good, but not the ideal one. Thanks though!

Comment: The emulator will NOT let you set up accounts on it

Comment: @caschw in the WP8 emulator, you can easily enough. With the WP7 emulator, it's possible just not as straight forward... http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/real-email-accounts-inside

Comment: @NeilTurner Thanks! Those two links gave me something to work with! I'll just wait out a little bit longer to see if more people have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think litmus provide the emulations you are looking for.